# on SQL how to find customer have purchase one product to multiple products

Tags: sql

I have data like this in Excel

```
Customer A - Milk-2018-active
Customer A - Bread-2019-active
customer B - Bike-2019-active
Customer C - kiwi-2019-active
Customer C - banana-2019-active
Customer C - apple-20120-active
```

I want to know how many customers I have who gone from one product to 2 or 3 products, so you can see that customer C had 2 products still active and now they have 3 products. same with customer A from 1to 2 products. but customer B have only one product, can anyone help me to write this in SQL?

Comment: provide your sample output in table format

Comment: I have removed the conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine the best way to achieve this without knowing how "active" field is used let alone everything else in the excel data. For example, do you only care about Year over Year, or does Y1 to Y3 jump count, etc. At any rate, you can probably accomplish this within Excel itself by using countifs and other functions, but if the data are large, then it could take some time. Here's one method which includes SQL, which makes some assumptions on your process. Modify as needed.

1. First, split that product-year-active flag into 3 fields in excel. So, excel would have four columns (Customer, Product, Year, Active).
2. Next, create a sql table and import your excel data into it using your desired method. I made all columns varchar in my test.
3. Lastly, if you simply want to count occasions where people's active product count went up by at least 1 from Y1 to Y2, or from Y2 to Y3, then here's your query...

   ```
    select count(distinct z.cid)
    from (
        with y1 as
        (select cid, count(distinct product) as products
        from my_temp1
        where year in ('2018')
        and active = 'active'
        group by 1
        ), 
        y2 as
        (select cid, count(distinct product) as products
        from my_temp1
        where year in ('2018','2019')
        and active = 'active'
        group by 1
        ), 
        y3 as 
        (select cid, count(distinct product) as products
        from my_temp1
        where year in ('2019','2020')
        and active = 'active'
        group by 1
        )
        select t.cid,
        coalesce(y1.products, 0) as products_year_1, 
        coalesce(y2.products, 0) as products_year_1_2,
        coalesce(y3.products, 0) as products_year_2_3
        from my_temp1 t
        left join y1 on y1.cid = t.cid
        left join y2 on y2.cid = t.cid
        left join y3 on y3.cid = t.cid
        )z
    where z.products_year_1_2 - z.products_year_1 >= 1
    or z.products_year_2_3 - z.products_year_1_2 >= 1
   ```